# Pytest celery: cleaned up database after task call

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery, pytest

I want to test celery task using pytest in Django.

If I use `celery_worker` parameter in test function then I get an error:

> {OperationalError}database table is locked (sqllite).

If I run worker before tests and do not use `celery_worker` parameter then task run seccesfully but I can't locate changes in the test database (`pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db`) as all updates links to the original database.

I try to run the test in Docker (`postgresql` db) but with parameter `celery_worker` I get error:

> psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `celery_worker` parameter in pair with pytest mark `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)`.